# Hidden Input Fields Pulling Incorrect Data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

This works:

```
   @if (brandFilters.Count != 0) { 
            @for (var i = 0; i < brandFilters.Count(); i++)
            {
                <li>
                    <input asp-for="@brandFilters[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
                    <label asp-for="@brandFilters[i].Selected">@brandFilters[i].Text</label>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@brandFilters[i].Value" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@brandFilters[i].Text" />
                </li>
            }    
        }
```

This doesn't work:

```
 @if (colorFilters.Count != 0) { 
            @for (var i = 0; i < colorFilters.Count(); i++)
            {
                <li>
                    <input asp-for="@colorFilters[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
                    <label asp-for="@colorFilters[i].Selected">@colorFilters[i].Text</label>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@colorFilters[i].Value" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@colorFilters[i].Text" />
                </li>
            }
        }
```

Confused? So am I. I'm using ViewData, that's bound in the controller, to send in a list of "SelectListItem" for both "Brand" and "Color". Both lists populate. Brand works flawlessly. It uses a GUID for it's value. Color, uses an integer for it's value. That's the only difference in anything here. The initial load of the full lists is fine. Adding and removing brands, updates the color options correctly (by removing them as selected items). The reverse is true. Selecting a color on initial load removes options from the brand selection. The difference here is, the hidden fields update correctly for brand, but the hidden fields remain SEQUENTIAL for the color checkboxes.

```
  <li>
                    <input class="form-check-input" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="colorFilters_0__Selected" name="colorFilters[0].Selected" value="true" />
                    <label for="colorFilters_0__Selected">Gold</label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="colorFilters_0__Value" name="colorFilters[0].Value" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="colorFilters_0__Text" name="colorFilters[0].Text" value="Black" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="form-check-input" onclick="this.form.submit();" type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="colorFilters_1__Selected" name="colorFilters[1].Selected" value="true" />
                    <label for="colorFilters_1__Selected">Red</label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="colorFilters_1__Value" name="colorFilters[1].Value" value="2" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="colorFilters_1__Text" name="colorFilters[1].Text" value="White" />
                </li>
```

The checkbox and label are getting the correct data. The correct value is being passed into the ViewData by the controller and checked at run time. The values should be 6 and 7, Red and Gold. Not 1 and 2, Black and White.

This is the code used to build the SelectListItem list:

```
ColorFilterListOutbound.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Value, Value = item.ColorListId.ToString(), Selected = false });
```

To recap: It all works fine, until i send back anything other than the full list of color checkboxes. Part of the data (visual) updates fine. Both hidden fields for each checkbox are taking old sequential data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When altering the number of checkboxes being provided, the ModelState maintained a list of previous checkboxes. Clearing the ModelState has resolved the immediate issue. I'll look into manipulation of the ModelState if necessary but clearing seems to be the way to go. I just have to reapply checks that were used previously to build out the new checkbox lists.